# What is the correct way to implement bullet functionality in powerpoint Autoshape

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

I made a function to apply custom bullets up to 5 levels parent, level 1, level 2, level 3 and none.

```
            shapeR.TextFrame.Ruler.Levels[1].FirstMargin = 0;
            shapeR.TextFrame.Ruler.Levels[1].LeftMargin = (float)40.53543;

            shapeR.TextFrame.Ruler.Levels[2].FirstMargin = 60;
            shapeR.TextFrame.Ruler.Levels[2].LeftMargin = (float)100.53543;

            shapeR.TextFrame.Ruler.Levels[3].FirstMargin = 120;
            shapeR.TextFrame.Ruler.Levels[3].LeftMargin = (float)160.53543;

            shapeR.TextFrame.Ruler.Levels[4].FirstMargin = 180;
            shapeR.TextFrame.Ruler.Levels[4].LeftMargin = (float)220.53543;

            shapeR.TextFrame.Ruler.Levels[5].FirstMargin = 240;
            shapeR.TextFrame.Ruler.Levels[5].LeftMargin = (float)280.53543;

            ApplyBulletStyle(bullet_Character, textR);//works good 
            //whats inside this function is  textR.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Character = '○'; with different characters

            PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.TextRange.IndentLevel = 1;//or 2 ,3,4 ,5
```

But this code doesn't work good some times

1. there is an indentation issue.
2. main issue occurs when I used numbered bullets like 4 lines or paragraphs have 1. ,2. type bullets and if I change middle oneto a),b) type bullet bullets of all para changes.

Also tried left indent property but second point error occurs.

I am using visual studio 2019 and addin express

Comment: In a well-constructed PowerPoint file, the bullet formatting is created in the slide master. Then the layouts inherit that from the master and the slides inherit the bullet format from the layouts. I think it likely that you're applying bulleting to the slide directly. The inheritance from the layout may be interfering with your formatting.